# PopUpPanel in GWT

Tags: gwt

I need to display a popup panel in GWT for login purpose on page load. I'm using MVP architecture, So the popup panel is in view class. How to load the popup panel?

Comment: Please write more detailed question. What do you want to be explained: archeticture or implementation example ?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't very clear what you're asking but I think you're looking for this:

```
   DialogBox db=new DialogBox();
   //I suppose you have created a panel login class
   LoginPanel lp;
   //Insert your login panel in the dialogbox
   db.add(lp);
   //Finally show the popup
   db.show();
```